# How can i get a two dimensional terraria like a map using python

Tags: python, game-development, procedural-generation, perlin-noise

I am trying to get a natural looking landscape like the game Terraria. I use a cellular automaton to generate caves and 1d Perlin noise for surface. The result is something like this: [my prototype](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QZV6F.png)

But this is not satisfactory to me because the original goal was to get something like that:
[what i want to get](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i9shQ.png)

I know that in the second case, Perlin noise is also used, but I have absolutely no idea how to achieve exactly this. Can someone suggest how I can achieve the second case with Perlin noise or not and/or give appropriate links on this topic ?

Answer (score 0):

What I would do:

1. Use Simplex not Perlin for your 2D noise. Simplex avoids a lot of the visible grid alignment characteristic of Perlin. You can see in [this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UZgCk.jpg), that the Perlin on the top follows 45 and 90 degree directions a lot. The noise I created/use/recommend would be <s>[this](https://github.com/KdotJPG/OpenSimplex2/blob/beb35cb70cbf1ffa5a5a5ce2470eee00f977c182/csharp/OpenSimplex2S.cs#L74), specifically the `Noise2_XBeforeY` function since it has the triangle grid rotated to try to look best for a Terraria-style game.</s> (EDIT: Since you are using Python, you could use [this](https://pypi.org/project/opensimplex/))
2. Start with `abs(noise(frequency*x, frequency*y)) < threshold ? cave : leave_solid`. Adjust frequency threshold until they produce the desired size/distribution.
3. Improve the shape and variation of caves by using fractal noise. `abs(noiseA(frequency*x, frequency*y) + noiseB(2*frequency*x, 2*frequency*y)*0.5 + ...) < threshold ? cave : leave_solid`
4. Compare against the height to make the caves get smaller as you go up. Replace threshold with some function of how far underground you are, e.g. `threshold = f(height(y) - y)`, where `f(t) =`  something like `t / (t + 1)`. Notice how `height(y) - y` gets bigger the further underground you are (assuming Y goes negative as you go down), and `t / (t + 1)` [preserves the increasingness but smoothly prevents it from exceeding 1](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=t+%2F+%28t+%2B+1%29). `f(t) = t / (t + 1)` probably won't work on its own, so you'll probably need to generalize it like `f(t) = thresholdMax * t / (thresholdIncreaseRate * t + 1)`. Pick values for thresholdMax and thresholdIncreaseRate which suit your purposes best.